# Accessing mongodb(mongoose) and then do something with it

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, express, mongoose

So I have a collection foo. I use ajax to access it. In the success portion I have a for loop

```
function(data){
  for(var i in data){
    var project = data[i]
  }
}
```

So now the collection is connected to project. How do I access project to get the 'name' so I can print out the names?

console.log(project[1].name)?

**EDIT more specifics:**
How come this does not work?

```
for(var i=0, i<project.length, i++){
    console.log(project[i].name);
}
```

It says there is a problem with '<' is says it is an unexpected token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to print this in your html, you can create a div and print your value inside the div.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = project[1].name;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

if you just want to see the value stored in project[1] in javascript use alert(project[1].name).

all honestly i don't see a need to create a "var project", you can just use "data" and skip the for loop

Comment: Helpful, but I was not quit specific enough. You did provide me with stuff I was looking for though any other thoughts about my edit?

Comment: $.each function is what I need to use. Not for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome developer tools or Firebug (firefox) to see what values are being returned.

In your "for" loop, write debugger; and the code will break as it iterates over the collection, or use the dev tools to set a break point.